# Service killed if sensor updates (too) slowly

Tags: java, android, wearables

I have a sensor event listener implemented in a Service which works fine as long as the sampling period and max report latency is under 1s, but as soon as I increase the sampling period over 1s the sensor wont update at all.

I want the sampling period to be 10s possibly 30s as the app I'm developing will need the rotation vector data over extended periods of time (5-10h) and I'm trying to save as much battery life on a smartwatch as possible.

I'll happily provide more information if I wasn't clear enough,

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem and apparently it's the device's hardware limitations.
You can find the max delay by calling `sensor.getMaxDelay`. If the delay is set to any higher the sensors delay will be set to that. However on older devices it may or may not work. [Link to android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getMaxDelay())

It seems that if you want a sensor slower than the max delay you'll have to implement some type of runnable or thread.